# extracting nth and mth lines everytime after a match is found without reading the whole file

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, match

I have the following sample text file:

```
DATASET
OBJTYPE "mesh2d"
BEGALD
ND 58673
NC 116294
TIMEUNITS SECONDS
TS 0  1.98849600e+08
    0.000000000e+00   
    0.56000000e+00   
    0.200000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00   
    0.100000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00   
    0.73400000e+00   
TS 0  1.98853209e+08
    0.00000000e+00   
    1.00500000e+00   
    4.00000000e+00   
    6.00000000e-05   
    9.00000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00   
TS 0  1.98856959e+08
    0.00000000e+00   
    1.38000000e+00   
    4.00000000e+00   
    3.00000000e-05   
    8.10000000e+00   
    2.45000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00   
TS 0  1.98860419e+08
    0.00000000e+00   
    1.40000000e+00   
    7.00000000e+00   
    3.00000000e-05   
    9.00000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00   
TS 0  1.98864081e+08
    0.00000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00   
    3.00000000e-05   
    0.00000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00   
TS 0  1.98867619e+08
    0.00000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00   
    8.00000000e+00   
    3.50000000e-05   
    10.00000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00   
    5.50000000e+00   
    0.00000000e+00
ENDDS
```

I want to extract the time stamps from the line starting with `'TS 0 '` and the 2nd, 5th and 8th  lines after every `'TS 0 '` match is found. Now, I have huge file which is more than 10 GB, so I don't want to read the whole file into memory.

This is what I could come up with:

```
with open(r"file") as f:
    for line in f:
       if line.startswith("TIMEUNITS SECONDS"):
           break  # file handlers will start from next line
    time=[] # list for storing time stamps 
    line2=[]   # or lines=[2,5,8] 
    line5=[]
    line8=[]
    line
    for line in f:
        
        if line.startswith("TS"):
            print(line.strip()) # extract all TS
            ts=float(line.split()[2])
        time.append(ts)
```

It only extracts the time stamps but how to extract the 2nd,5th and 8th lines using a loop or any other faster method without reading the whole file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A file object is iterable in python, and retains its position between calls to `iter`, which you've used to skip the initial section. Keep using the same technique to find the lines you need:

```
with open(r"file") as f:
    for line in f:
       if line.startswith("TIMEUNITS SECONDS"):
           break
    time = [] 
    line2 = []
    line5 = []
    line8 = []
    for line in f:
        if line.startswith("TS"):
            ts = float(line.strip().split()[2])
            time.append(ts)
            for _ in range(2):
                line = next(file)
            line2.append(float(line.strip()))
            for _ in range(3):
                line = next(file)
            line5.append(float(line.strip()))
            for _ in range(3):
                line = next(file)
            line8.append(float(line.strip()))
```

Now that you have the basic structure down, you can factor out the repeated code into a function and add some error checking:

```
def find(file, s):
    for line in file:
        if line.startswith(s):
            return line
    return None

def skip(file, n):
    for i, line in zip(range(n), file):
        pass
    return line if i == n - 1 else None

def load(filename):
    with open(filename) as f:
        if not find(f, "TIMEUNITS SECONDS"):
            return None

        time = [] 
        line2 = []
        line5 = []
        line8 = []
        while True:
            if not (line := find(f, "TS")):
                break
            time.append(float(line.strip().split()[2]))
            if not (line := skip(f, 2)):
                break
            line2.append(float(line.strip()))
            if not (line := skip(f, 3):
                break
            line5.append(float(line.strip()))
            if not (line := skip(f, 3):
                break
            line8.append(float(line.strip()))
    return time, line2, line5, line8
```

Comment: Thank you so much, Mr. Mad Physicist! Learned something new!